# Cassandra data in one node growing rapidly

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I have migrated records form old columnfamily to new columnfamily. in testKeyspace.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace WITH replication = {
  'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
  'DC1': '2',
  'DC2': '2'
};
```

Old Columnfamily Structure.

```
CREATE TABLE old_Columnfamily (
  scopeid bigint,
  formid bigint,
  time timestamp,
  ipaddress text,
  record_link_id bigint,
  user_ifuid bigint,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((scopeid, formid), time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
CREATE INDEX update_audit_id_idx ON old_Columnfamily (record_link_id);

CREATE INDEX update_audit_user_ifuid_idx ON old_Columnfamily (user_ifuid);
```

New Columnfamily Structure

```
CREATE TABLE new_Columnfamily (
  scopeid bigint,
  formid bigint,
  time timeuuid,
  ipaddress inet,
  operation int,
  record_id bigint,
  value text,
  ifuid bigint,
PRIMARY KEY ((scopeid), formid, time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (formid ASC, time DESC)

CREATE INDEX audit_operation_idx ON new_Columnfamily (operation);
CREATE INDEX audit_recordid_idx ON new_Columnfamily (record_id);
CREATE INDEX audit_zuid_idx ON new_Columnfamily (ifuid);
```

The nodetool status result is

```
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address              Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.xxx.xxx.x80   5.58 GB   256     15.5%  fda5181f-baf6-4c2d-9bf9-ecc4abc50c39  RAC1
UN  172.xxx.xxx.x29   6.63 GB   256     16.4%  12574f5e-538a-4386-8c34-c8603a7456be  RAC1
UN  172.xxx.xxx.x22  40.64 GB    256     17.2%  db390d80-161f-44fb-a9d8-536ea924533d  RAC1
Datacenter: DC2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address              Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  172.xxx.xxx.x20   4.65 GB   256     17.9%  fda5181f-baf6-4c2d-9bf9-ecc4abc50c39  RAC1
UN  172.xxx.xxx.x67   6.37 GB   256     16.7%  12574f5e-538a-4386-8c34-c8603a7456be  RAC1
UN  172.xxx.xxx.x23  6.93 GB    256     16.2%  db390d80-161f-44fb-a9d8-536ea924533d  RAC1
```

Edit:
nodetool -h 172.xxx.xxx.x23 tpstats

```
s =  -ea -javaagent:./../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms8G -Xmx8G -Xmn400M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
ReadStage                         0         0       24426641         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0       48496365         0                 0
MutationStage                     0         0       15623599         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0        2562071         0                 0
ReplicateOnWriteStage             0         0              0         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0        3268659         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0             32         0                 0
MemoryMeter                       0         0            371         0                 0
MemtablePostFlusher               0         0          32263         0                 0
FlushWriter                       0         0          18447         0              1080
MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              8         0                 0
commitlog_archiver                0         0              0         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0             12         0                 0
HintedHandoff                     2         2           1194         0                 0

Message type           Dropped
RANGE_SLICE                  0
READ_REPAIR                  0
PAGED_RANGE                  0
BINARY                       0
READ                         0
MUTATION                     0
_TRACE                       0
REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
```

Problem Is:
while migrating data from old to new columnfamily node **172.xxx.xxx.x23** went down. I stopped the migration and started the node again and then started migration. 
I noticed data in node **172.xxx.xxx.x23** growing rapidly.

why this happened? please explain the reason. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there is difference in the partition key between old ((scopeid, formid), time) and new schema ((scopeid), formid, time). Since you reduce the partition key uniqueness to one column your partition key calculated could impact the data storage on the nodes.  If you have same scopeid from thousands of records all will go on same node, because partition key for all those records will be same.

Comment: Right, But if you see replication value is 2 so atleast two node data should increase.

Comment: did you check if hints are being stored in the node which is growing in size

Comment: here I have 2 active and 2 pending HintedHandoff  which was 0 yesterday.